# Make a Bitmap "orbit" a point

Tags: java, android, rotation

I am trying to make a "wheel of buttons" - 
I have a custom "Button" object that uses a Rect for it's position/size.

I can get one to rotate by doing this:

```
Button1.Rectangle.left = (int) (Vertex.x + (radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Degree))));
Button1.Rectangle.top =  (int) (Vertex.y + (radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(Degree))));
Button1.Rectangle.right = Button1.Rectangle.left + ButtonSize;
Button1.Rectangle.bottom = Button1.Rectangle.top + ButtonSize;

    Degree += 1;
```

Unfortunately, this only works for one because they then all line up on eachother...how do I incorporate an "offset", or increment instead of assign the location

I've tried:

```
 //Using self position as vertex
    Button1.Rectangle.left = (int) (Button1.Rectangle.left + (radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Degree))));
    Button1.Rectangle.top =  (int) (Button1.Rectangle.top + (radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(Degree))));
```

and

```
// using +=
 Button1.Rectangle.left += (int) (Vertex.x + (radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(Degree))));
Button1.Rectangle.top +=  (int) (Vertex.y + (radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(Degree))));
```

I know it must be something fairly easy, I'm just missing it...

EDIT:

Fixed it by making a"

```
int Degree1 = 0;
int Degree2 = 90;
int Degree3 = 180;
etc.
```

and incrementing them:

```
Degree1 += 1;
Degree2 += 1;
Degree3 += 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the origin point that you're rotating around, and each time you go to compute its location, compute against the origin, not the current point.

Comment: thats what the Vector2 called "Vertex" is, it's the center point of the screen - the problem is it assigns the position so all the buttons appear in one location....maybe if each has there own "Degree" variable?